# Heroku database missing field from Django Models

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, migrate

Running a Django app on Heroku. Locally, I'm using the `db.sqlite3 db`, while on Heroku, it's the PostgreSQL.

I have one migration, reflecting locally, but not in Heroku, where it keeps giving me an error that "it can't find a field".
I haven't configured PostgreSQL in any special way, so far I just ran

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

and that seemed to do the trick.

How can I make the field change update in Heroku's db?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku won't run migrations for you automatically - that is why it worked when you ran `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

If you want automatic migrations the easiest way to do this is by adding this at the end of your `Procfile`

`release: python manage.py migrate`

Any new migration you add to your django app will be automatically applied